# How to choose a different query based on the subject of an object in SPARQL?

Tags: sparql

Let's say I have the following data

```
subject = david
predicate = knows
object1 = Amy
object2 = Brian

subject = Amy
predicate = gender
object = female

subject = Brian
predicate = gender
object = male
```

Now I want to find all the people david knows but perform different queries based upon their gender so the pseudocode would look something like this:

```
SELECT ?something
WHERE{

david rdf:knows ?person

if{?person rdf:gender "female"} 
{ do this query}
else if {?person rdf:gender "male"}
{do this query} 
}
```

From what I've seen SPARQL if statements can only print out information and cannot be used to make decisions on what query to execute.

If anyone knows how the above can be achieved I would be most grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you could do something like:

```sql
select ?something where {
   :David :knows ?person

   optional {
     ?person :gender "female" .
     #-- more query
   }
   optional {
     ?person :gender "male" .
     #-- more query
   }
}
```

Both of the optional parts are optional, and only the one with the matching gender will be able to match, so it's essentially a conditional query.  Note that you'll do both if you have data like `:person :gender "male", "female"`, and that you'll do neither if you don't have a gender provided.